# Wordpress/Godaddy: How can I tell if this .htaccess has malware in it? wp-currentver.php

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, malware

Godaddy flagged my /html/.htaccess file as possible malware.

Is this malicious? 
Fwiw, it also flagged wp-currentver.php as possible malware.

My site *looks* fine, appears to be functioning fine.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (google|yahoo|msn|aol|bing) [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} (google|yahoo|msn|aol|bing)
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /wp-currentver.php?p=$1 [L]
# BEGIN WordPress

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got hacked.

Those are redirects that detect if someone is coming through Google search results with Google as a referrer; the standard WordPress (non-Multisite) rewrite block is at https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess i.e.:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

And the file `wp-currentver.php` is malicious and not WordPress core. Also see https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/f4Cw1k1-j6g

Carefully follow [FAQ My site was hacked - WordPress Codex.](https://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked)

Find a more secure host.

Then take a look at the recommended security measures in [Hardening WordPress - WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress) and [Brute Force Attacks - WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Brute_Force_Attacks)

Comment: FWIW I also found a copy of what should be in htacess: htaccess - WordPress Codex https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess